# Evaluate ID of checkbox in the onclick method

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a razor page with some checkboxes on it. I would like to evaluate the checkbox ID after a CB was clicked. Thats what I have so far:

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="CB_a" @onchange="eventArgs => { UpdateButton(eventArgs.Value); }"  />

@code {

private void UpdateButton(object checkedValue)
    {

    }

}
```

What's the correct syntax to send the id of the textfield (CB_a) as a 2nd parameter to the UpdateButton method?

Answer (score 1):

```cs
<input type="checkbox" id="CB_a" @onchange="eventArgs => { UpdateButton(eventArgs.Value, "CB_a"); }"  />

@code {
    private void UpdateButton(object checkedValue, string id)
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: I think the OP has more than one checkbox. I think you can just use "CB_a" again instead of `id`. Avoiding the repetition looks like a challenge.

Comment: The repetition can lead to subtle bugs (people tend to forget to change both strings), I would recommend it only for very simple scenarios

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind wrapping your input into a component:

```
<MyInput id="Cb_a" OnChange="(e)=> { UpdateButton(e.Item1.Value, e.Item2); }"></MyInput>
<MyInput id="Cb_b" OnChange="(e)=> { UpdateButton(e.Item1.Value, e.Item2); }"></MyInput>
<MyInput id="Cb_c" OnChange="(e)=> { UpdateButton(e.Item1.Value, e.Item2); }"></MyInput>
<MyInput id="Cb_d" OnChange="(e)=> { UpdateButton(e.Item1.Value, e.Item2); }"></MyInput>

@code{

    private void UpdateButton(object value, string id)
    {

    }

}
```

and your component looks something like this:

```
MyInput.razor:

<input type="checkbox"  @onchange="(e)=>OnChange.InvokeAsync(new Tuple<ChangeEventArgs, string>(e, id))" id="@id" />

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public string id { get; set;}

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<Tuple<ChangeEventArgs,string>> OnChange { get; set; }

}
```